# Reading RAW resources and saving into Internal storage

Tags: android, inputstream, android-resources

I am trying to create internal storage folder(s) and copy over my RAW files to those folder. I have following method

**EDIT**

```
private byte[] buffer = null;
private String DIR_NAME = "images/sample_images";

public void storeRAWFilesToInternalStorage()
{
buffer = new byte[3000000];

mFilesDir = tempContext.getFilesDir();
mImagesDir = new File(mFilesDir, DIR_NAME);

if (!mImagesDir.exists() && !mImagesDir.isDirectory()) dirCreated = mImagesDir.mkdirs();

InputStream fileStream = tempContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.desert);
fileStream.read(buffer);
fileWithinMyDir = new File(mImagesDir, "my_sample_image.jpg");
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir);

outputStream.write(buffer);
outputStream.close();
}
```

it works fine, however I have following questions.

What is the buffer size should I assign since I dont know the bytes size of each file. If I assign more than required then I am wasting memory. If I am assigning less than required then image wont be saved properly.

Also, I see the image saved in my Internal Storage (using ES Fileexplorer to view files), but when I try to open it, it doesnt show up. Weird.

**END EDIT**

Also what if I have 100 RAW files which I would like to copy to my Internal Folder, say "images". I dont want to type following thousand of times.

```
InputStream fileStream = tempContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.**asset_name**);
```

Is there a way to loop through all raw resources, read them and store them to Internal Storage folder? Can I see some code snippet?

Comment: Most likely either tempContext is null at the point where you try to run that, or else your resource doesn't exist.  Is the exception on the openRawResource line, or on the line where you try to read the fileStream?   As for avoiding typing, you can create an array of R.raw.asset_name numbers and iterate through it.

Comment: tempContext and fileStream both are not null.I tested it. **fileStream.read(buffer);** is the line where the Null pointer exception happens.

Comment: Is your buffer still null at that point?  You won't be able to read into one until you allocate it.  Also, please post the actual stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the advice. I updated my actual code snippet, and not getting exception anymore. However, I have following questions. What is the buffer size should I assign since I dont know the bytes size of each file. If I assign more than required then I am wasting memory. If I am assigning less than required then image wont be saved properly. Also, I see the image saved in my Internal Storage (using ES Fileexplorer to view files), but when I try to open it, it doesnt show up. Weird.

Comment: One would typically use a reasonable sized buffer and move data in a loop until the task is finished.